# How to optimize count of queries in Django admin for custom fields from another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm, sql-optimization

I have the problem with SQL queries optimization for custom list_display field "balance".
For getting account balance query executed  for each row. What is the way to avoid it and to make  count queryes fixed.
I trying to user `prefetch_related` but this is doesnt have any effects.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserAdminForm
    fields = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'middle_name',
        'groups'
    ]
    list_display = [
        'username_',
        'person_name',
        'balance',
    ]

    def balance(self, obj):
        balance = obj.person.customer.customeraccount_set.first().account.balance
        return balance
    balance.allow_tags = True
    balance.short_description = 'Balance'


    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('person__customer__customeraccount_set__account', queryset=CustomerAccount.objects.all()),
            'person', 'person__customer', 'person__customer__customeraccount_set',
        ).filter(groups__name='водитель')
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
```

Screen from debug tool bar:
[image]

Comment: You are not prefetching customeraccount model. You need to prefetch this to avoid N+1 queries.

Comment: Now i prefetched customer account model but this is doesn't work. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't prefetch an entire collection to show a single item from it. That could result in poor performance as well. Instead use a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to fetch a single property from that collection.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

class UserAdmin(...):
    ...

    def balance(self, obj):
        balance = obj.customer_account_balance
        return balance
    balance.allow_tags = True
    balance.short_description = 'Balance'


    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).select_related(
            'person', 'person__customer',
        ).filter(groups__name='водитель').annotate(
            customer_account_balance=Subquery(
                CustomerAccount.objects.filter(
                    user_id=OuterRef('id')
                ).order_by(
                    'id' # I don't know how you want to select the balance, but this is where you'd order it.
                ).values('balance')[:1]
            )
        )
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
```